# Binding DocumentDb Query to Azure Functions input

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions

Is it possible to bind a documentDb query to the input on an Azure Function?

I don't need the query to be a trigger, but I'd like to pass the results of the query in when my function is triggered

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-documentdb/#docdboutput you can specify an output binding to do what you need

Comment: @Thomas I'm looking for an input binding that will give me the results of a query.  Not an output binding, which would let me add a new document

Comment: And do the input binding in the documentatoin can match your requirement ?

Comment: @Thomas Not as far as I can see. If I'm missing a binding option please let me know. Note that, I'm looking for the results of a query, which could be multiple results.  The as far as I can tell the input bindings only give a single document.

Comment: Yeah seems that you need to implement your own binding :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zain,

Currently, you're limited to setting the document ID. Advanced queries are not supported by the binding.

The alternative is to bind to the client and execute the query directly.

We have an issue tracking that here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/289

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can make calls out to DocumentDB from an Azure Function. Collect whatever parameters you need from the Azure Function call, compose your query, send it out to DocumentDB, wait for the results, and respond to the Azure Function call (assuming you are using an HTTP trigger).

I use node.js to access DocumentDB and the SDK seems to load fine as a package.json dependency from within Azure Functions. I suspect the same is true with .NET.

Comment: yeah, I know I could manually invoke DocumentDb. I was hoping for a solution where the Azure Functions framework would do most of the connection management work for me